# Android Material Calendarview setOnDateChangedListener only to specific days

Tags: java, android, calendarview

I am using Material Clanedarview to build a custom calendar, I add decorators to specefic days of the week, for example Saturday and sunday, and it works fine, but I also want to setOndateChangedListener to only this 2 days, so when the user click on other days of the calendar the click did nothing but when the user click on saturday and sunday i want to start another intent.
How can i set onDateChangedListener to specific days? thanks

```
 mcv.addDecorators(new BookingDecorator(myColor,diasFor));
    mcv.setOnDateChangedListener(new OnDateSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSelected(@NonNull MaterialCalendarView widget, @NonNull CalendarDay date, boolean selected) {
            //I WANT TO OPEN INTENT ONLY FOR SPECIFIC DAYS
        }
    });
```

Comment: With an `if` statement?

Comment: Yes, but i think this library has a specific way to enable or disable click listener

Comment: check the selected day if equal the wanted days start the intent you need else msg "selected wrong days"

Answer (score 0):

CalendarDay has a method `day.getDate().getDayOfWeek()`, you can use that.